# Linking user's home to another disk

Tags: mount, users, symlink, disk, home

I wish to mount a new disk at `/disk` on my raspberry server. My `/home/iago-lito` folder and the `/root` folder are standing on the SD card, which is fine to me. But I would like subsequent new user home folders to be stored on the disk.

Instead of messing around with partitions and `/home/newuser{1,2,3,..}` mounting points, I intend to simply link each home folder to the disk, with:

```
ln -s /disk/home/newuser1 /home/newuser1
```

Is it okay to do something that simple? Are there downsides in terms of safety, performance or security?

Comment: It might get very confusing if the amount of users grow. Alternatively you also could configure a different user `HOME` directory than `/home/<user>` when creating the user. It also could be `/disk/home/<user>` which can also be changed in `/etc/passwd` afterwards.

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean `adduser newuser1 --home /disk/home/newuser1`? This sounds neat. What should I do with `/etc/passwd` then?

Comment: Yes, `--home` would set the location of the user's home directory. You do not have to toch `/etc/passwd` if you create the user with `--home`. That only would be necessary if you already added a user with `/home/<user>` and want to change it to `/disk/home/<user>`.

Comment: @Thomas Great. Feel free to post `adduser newuser --home /any/fancy/location` as an answer then :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating symbolic links for each user home directory might get confusing if the amount of users grow and you have to take care of creating the symbolic links.

Alternatively you also could configure a different user `HOME` directory than `/home/<user>` when creating the user.
It also could be `/disk/home/<user>` which can also be changed/moved afterwards or for already existing users in `/etc/passwd` or by using `usermod`.

Depending on your distribution, the option to change default user home directory when creating the user would be `--home` or `--home-dir`. In doubt look it up in the corresponding `man` page.
An example for your case would be as follows.

```
adduser newuser --home /disk/home/newuser
```